# PSPath for registry `registry:: ` - why double colons?

Tags: powershell, registry

In PS when we use Get-ChildItem to get the children of Registry, we use `registry::` instead of `registry:`. For other locations we give the path as c:\, d:\ Why is there an extra : for registry?

This is not a duplicate of the question asked regarding static method calls in .NET. 
Neither do I know .NET nor is this a complicated programming related question. It is simply about the path notion which is different for registry.

Comment: [Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/working-with-registry-keys?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to the PSPath, this is the notation both for the registry provider and the location. This is different from the notation for a PSDrive.

```
Provider::Location
```

Example FileSystem

```
Get-ChildItem C:\example.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath

Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\example.txt
```

Example Registry

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Example | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath

Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Example
```

Note that in my examples the PSDrives (C and HKLM) only have one colon. HKLM and HKCU are builtin PSDrives to registry locations. You can retrieve the full list by using the `Get-PSDrive` cmdlet.

Comment: @Ammu In that call you are just defining which provider to use, you can do the same with `FileSystem` e.g. `Get-ChildItem filesystem::C:\Example.txt`

Comment: Get-ChildItem registry::  - This is what I give to get the hive.
Get-ChildItem c:\  - This is what I give to get the children of C:\ 
My question is why  does the notation differ for registry.

Comment: why not just use get-ChildItem registry:

Comment: @Ammu You can get to the registry without statically defining the provider. `Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software` is functionally the same as `Get-ChildItem Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software`

Comment: So it is just a notation to differentiate  Registry Provider from Drive. Got it! Thanks a lot!